# securing web application with spring boot - causing thymeleaf exception

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to go through some of spring boot tutorials. 
I imported this one in eclipse: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

At the step "Create an unsecured web application", I launched it in eclipse. It starts ok, and then I open http://localhost:8080 in my browser, and I get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Mar 26 15:15:03 GMT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I can see the following error in the console in eclipse:

```
2016-03-26 15:15:03.598 ERROR 4464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "home": Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
2016-03-26 15:15:03.629 ERROR 4464 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

The stack trace is longer, I can provide it if needed.

Other than this, I didn't change the source code of the tutorial from the initial state (which is inside the initial directory in the example)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error Error resolving template `home` means the view resolver could not find any template matching this path.

Spring Boot Starter Thymeleaf will configure a default view resolver that will expect to find your html file at the following location : `src/main/resources/templates/`. Make sure `home.html` is found at that location. If it is, check if you don't have an exception occuring before the one you sent us.

Regards,
Daniel